# Preact change webpack css loader config

Tags: webpack, preact, css-loader, preact-cli

I'd like to change the webpack config on Preact to have only hashed class names, and make them shorter as well if it's a safe practice.

The css loader works fine on my preact project but sometimes the component is visible in the class names even though the modules.css file is referenced by that component alone.

https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/wiki/Config-Recipes#setting-proxy-for-dev-server-using-config-directly

I've came across this documentation but I'm not experienced enough to get this to work and I'm looking for the specific code to write in my preact.config.js

Comment: Hi, `preact-cli` maintainer here. Can you provide more detail, such as current behavior vs expected behavior side-by-side? I don't really understand what "ometimes the component is visible in the class names even though the modules.css file is referenced by that component alone" means.

Comment: I meant some class names contain hashed characters only whilst others have the file/component name as a prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following config should be what you're after, but let me know if you have any issues with it:

```js
// preact.config.js

/**
 * @param {import('preact-cli').Config} config - original webpack config
 * @param {import('preact-cli').Env} env - current environment and options pass to the CLI
 * @param {import('preact-cli').Helpers} helpers - object with useful helpers for working with the webpack config
 */
export default (config, env, helpers) => {
    const { loader: cssLoader } = helpers.getLoadersByName(config, 'css-loader')[0];
    cssLoader.options.modules.localIdentName = '[hash:base64:5]';
}
```

The general idea here is that we get the `css-loader` using `preact-cli`'s config helpers ([documented here](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/wiki/Webpack-Config-Helpers)), but specifically the first one; the first is for CSS Modules, or the CSS you author in `components/` and `routes/`. The second `css-loader` instance is for all other CSS you author, which won't be hashed, so we'll ignore it and only get the first (`[0]`).

Then, we simply update the options. The [default value can be found here](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/blob/73232fdea928b072ba4cdaadd464c174adf7e9cd/packages/cli/src/lib/webpack/webpack-base-config.js#L252), and we simply alter it to only use the hash, dropping the `local__` part.

Regarding making the hashes shorter, I would not. Any shorter and you drastically increase the chances of triggering a collision in caches.